# Autofill By passing set parameters on Form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, autofill, bypass

I am having a problem with a form on our site. I recently made an Auto-Formatting script for the form and and put requirements in, but if a user auto-fills it jumps pass the requirements and won't format since its done via keystroke

I tried below

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="phoneNumberFormatter()" class="form-control phone-number" id="phone-number" pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" maxlength="14" name="phone" placeholder="*Phone Example: ###-###-####" 
                                        oninput="setCsutomValidity('')"
                                        oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Not Valid')"    
                                        onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}"    
                                               required>
```

but this only worked on keystrokes and not autofill

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you update the question with a minimal code example of the JavaScript functions?